# Get svn log for a user's activity on a specific date

Tags: svn

How can I see *all* svn logs that I made on a specific date?

I've searched the web for this, but haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: If you're on Windows, TortoiseSVN lets you filter its log output by (among other things) user name. If you're on Unix, I have no doubt that there's a way to cook up a script that executes `svn log -rNNNNN` for each revision number in `svn log -revision {startdate}:{enddate} | grep ajitam`, although I'm too weak in shell scripting to do that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To show entries for username on the 10th:

```
svn log -r '{2010-12-10}:{2010-12-11}'|sed -n '1p; 2,/^-/d; /username/,/^-/p'
```

The SVN command gets commits in that date range

Breakdown of the sed command:

- `-n` - Don't automatically print.
- `1p` - Print the first line (the --- header).
- `2,/^-/d;` - Remove everything from the second through the closing --- header.  This removes the first entry, which IIRC is the most recent commit as of midnight at the beginning of the day (i.e. it's not actually in the range, and may be long in the past).
- `/username/,/^-/p` - Print everything starting from that username (a regex matching the user you're interested in) to the closing --- header (this acts repeatedly)

Comment: @pyfunc it works for me. Problem with 'grep' is that you get only first line of each log

Comment: Who down-voted this?  It works.  I know because both I (before posting) and ajitam tested it.  It may require GNU sed.

Comment: @ajitam : It's ok. My understanding is based on what you provide. I am sure you did not want a cookie cutter solution. Since you did not provide any details. I understood that you are looking to find commits on a specific date. That is what I provided. It is sufficient to build on from there. See AgentConundrum's answer. In providing a partial answer, I get two negative votes. Very funny. Matthew Flaschen's answer did not even work for me. So i guess the grep and rest would need to be specifically built. AgentConundrum's answer is more generic and in line of what I had suggested.

Comment: @Matthew: FYI, your solution works for me as well (though mine is a bit easier to follow - no offense, of course)

Comment: @py, how is it incorrect on your repo?  I am using svn 1.6.5 and GNU sed 4.2.1.

Comment: As question doesn't specify whether the platform is *nix or Windows, this is not a correct answer for Windows users.

Comment: That certainly doesn't make it "not an answer", @Ozil. Since the question *doesn't* specify a platform, a Gnu/Unix answer is perfectly valid and has obviously been quite helpful over the years. If you'd like to post a Windows answer, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're on a Linux system, you could do something like this:

`svn log -r {YYYY-MM-DD}:{YYYY-MM-DD} | grep username | cut -d " " -f 1 | tail -n +2 | while read revision; do svn log -r $revision; done`

What this is doing is running svn log to get all logs for a given day, then cutting the output so that it is just a list of revision numbers. [Edit: Added `tail -n +2` to cut off the first revision - as @Matthew mentions, that first line would be the most recent revision before `{that_day}`] The while loop then iterates over each line of revision numbers, passing it to `svn log`.

Also, remember that {YYYY-MM-DD} refer to midnight at the *start* of that day, so to run the whole day you should run it for `{that_day}:{the_following_day}`.

Hope that helps!

(Also, sorry for the confusion earlier about `--username`. I've never used it before, and because my local svn only has one user (me), it *looked* like it worked, when it really wasn't.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the same date issue as pyfunc's answer.  It includes a commit *before* `that_day`.  Also, it's somewhat inefficient because every call to svn log requires a process, a network connection, and potentially a password prompt.

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for pointing out the "last commit before" problem. I've updated my solution. You're absolutely correct that this would suck over a network or with uncached credentials though.

Comment: @Agent, +1, thanks for the update.  You're right that despite the performance issues, it's more readable (especially if one isn't familiar with sed).

Comment: @Matthew: If it was in a script somewhere, and you documented it, yours is far superior where the performance matters (for instance, I wouldn't want to run this against the repo for the svn project itself). If it's just on a local network and you're not pulling too many revisions, mine is "good enough for government work".

Comment: +1 for mentioning the start of day 'feature' in Subversion's log display.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn log --verbose --search user_name --revision {YYYY-MM-DD}:{YYYY-MM-DD}
```

Works on any platform

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux the best solution for getting whole date logs is as follows:

```
svn log -r {start date}:{end date} -v | sed -n ‘/username/,/—–$/ p’
```

If you wants to retrieve SVN logs on the basis of username and between the given date range then you need use `svn log -r {startDate}:{endDate}` which is piped with `sed` command for username.